# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un input type file u otro en función de la opción que seleccione en un combo <select>?

Tags: java, html, web, jsp

```
<h2>Escoge opcion</h2>

        <select  name="opcion" id="opcion">

    <%                        
           for (int i = 0; i < arrayOpciones.size(); i++) {

    %>

            <option value="<%=arrayOpciones.get(i)%>"><%=arrayOpciones.get(i)%></option>

                <% } %>

        </select>

            <h2><p>Seleccione fichero:&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /></h2>

            <input type="file" name="fichero" id="ficheroCarga" accept=".txt">
            <input type="file" name="fichero" id="ficheroCarga" accept=".xls">
```

En las dos ultimas lineas de código me muestra botones para seleccionar un archivo. En uno solo me acepta txt y en otro excel. Quiero que si la opción seleccionada en el combo generado en las líneas anteriores es 'op1', se muestre solo el que acepta txt y si es 'op2', el que acepta excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con JavaScript podrias generar una funcion con el evento onblur, onchange,... te oculte uno u otro. Mas o menos, el codigo se me ocurre que podria ser algo asi:

```
    function myFunction() {
//repetir practicamente este codigo para "jugar con los inputs"
      var x = document.getElementById("ficheroCarga"); 
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

Por otro lado, dentro del codigo que muestras, deberias de ponerle o identificadores distintos o nombres distintos para poder identificarlos con el JS

Tambien tienes que tener en cuenta cual quieres ocultar al inicio del programa y ocultarlo desde un evento en el body (onload)